# How to show full nodes in views in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, view

Using Views module in Drupal 6 I wish to not only to show differents fields of the nodes, as one usually does. I wish to show all the nodes (matching criteria) in their complete form. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the `frontpage` view - it's one of the standard ones that comes with the [`Views`](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.

Looks like what you need to set is as follows:

**Basic Settings**

- *Style:* Unformatted
- *Row style:* Node

**Row Style Options**

- *Build Mode:* Teaser or Full Node

(Using `Views 6.x-2.5` and `Views UI 6.x-2.5`)